# How to create a class to use with LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to create a simple class with variables in that I can assign data to and then use LINQ to update a database.

My class looks like this:

```
Public Class GoalDetails
Inherits System.Object

Public Id As Integer
Public GoalTime As Integer
Public Scorer As String
Public HomeAway As String
End Class
```

My code to assign variables and then insert is:

```
Dim goalsToDb = New GoalDetails()
goalsToDb.Id = 1
goalsToDb.GoalTime = 87
goalsToDb.Scorer = "W Rooney"
goalsToDb.HomeAway = "Home"

db.Goals.InsertOnSubmit(goalsToDb)

db.SubmitChanges()
```

I get the message "Value of type 'GoalDetails' cannot be converted to 'Goal'.

I'm using the same code with another class that is in a third party DLL and it works, but of course I can't see the code of that class to see how it differs from mine.

Comment: You are trying to insert a `GoalDetails`object into the `Goals` table.  Either change the type of object that your populating or insert into the right table. (`GoalDetails`?)  If you're expecting it to accept _any_ type that has the same property values then you are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a statically typed language.  Even if two types are *conceptually similar* they are still entirely different types.  You can't use them interchangeably.

This property:

```
db.Goals
```

Is a collection of a given type.  (Possibly named `Goal`?)  You can only add items *of that type* to that collection.  Something like this:

```
Dim goalsToDb = New Goal() ' or whatever the type is called, you'd have to confirm
goalsToDb.Id = 1
goalsToDb.GoalTime = 87
goalsToDb.Scorer = "W Rooney"
goalsToDb.HomeAway = "Home"

db.Goals.InsertOnSubmit(goalsToDb)

db.SubmitChanges()
```

You can create custom classes to hold your data within your application.  But when using your data access framework's generated code (Entity Framework?  LINQ to SQL?) then you have to use the types generated by that framework.  So if you use a custom class throughout your application then you'd need to convert its values to the database class when interacting with the database.

Comment: I see it now, I didn't need to create my own class, I needed to use the one it creates automatically when I import my tables into my LINQ to SQL class. It's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the two types Goal and GoalDetails. You can not use db.Goals.InsertOnSubmit() to insert data in GoalDetails table. In order to do so, you need to come up with something like db.**GoalDetails**.InsertOnSubmit() which will take an object of GoalDetails and insert into GoalDetails table.

Also, if you want to see a class from 3rd party DLL, you can use IL disassemblers like [ILSpy](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/ILSpy.shtml)